# Compiling a RSweave file: File is not ASCII

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, rstudio

Here is my problem:

```
\begin{verbatim}

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

\end{verbatim}
```

I keep getting this error message when I compile it:

> grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE); utils::Sweave('Applied04.Rnw')
>   Error: ‘Applied04.Rnw’ is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding
>   Execution halted

I have no idea what is going on. I have used verbatim already. Can someone tell me what is wrong here please ?

Comment: "‘Applied04.Rnw’ is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding" - is that message so unclear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the "smart" (non-ASCII) single quotes with apostrophes.

I'm not quite sure why you're putting this in verbatim: is this part of a debugging exercise, or do you really want that?  More likely, you want

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your LaTeX preamble *or*

```
options(useFancyQuotes=FALSE)
```

in your R setup code.

Answer (score 3):

Normally this error arising from the encoding you are using. you need to be careful when saving your files, ensuring that they are in utf8, on occasion some programs are by default in ISO 8859-1 or another (here a little explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

So this is a possible solution:

```
Stangle("Applied04.Rnw",output="Code.R",encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: I'm sorry @jose-ricardo-bustos-m , I'll remember next time.

Answer (score 2):

The error is likely induced by using any fancy symbols that are part of the chosen local keyboard layout, for example I used a German umlaut somewhere in the Rnw-file and then I got this error message. Thus, if you get this error message, look through your whole file for non-ASCII letters or symbols and replace them appropriately if for some other reason you do not want to add the \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}.